# CSS not working for IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a shopping cart display button on the top of my site and its supposed to show a red price for the total in your cart

the CSS works in FF and in chrome, but not in IE.

CSS:

```
.cart-info {
background-image: url("/skin/frontend/default/photo/images/header/head-cart-bg.gif");
background-position: left center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
color: #264796;
height: 38px;
padding: 19px 0 0 50px;
width: 150px;
font-weight: bold;
}

.cart_price {
color: #c70000;
font-weight: bold;
float: left;
font: 14px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
left: 114px;
position: absolute;
top: 57px;
width: auto;
}
.cart_price a {
float: left;
margin: 2px 0 0 8px;
}
```

Comment: Does it not show at all, or is it just off? If so, what is off? Also, share a bit of the HTML for it.

Comment: Just like the old million monkeys will eventually get shakespeare right, so will ie eventually get css correct.  Unfortunately, Microsoft seems to use a different pool of monkeys for each release.  Thus different versions of ie support css differently.  you may need conditional comments (google it for details) for each version of ie about which you care.

Comment: it shows it as white font as opposed to the red color i have in the CSS

Comment: if the problem is on ie6-7, it could be a problem with the position:absolute and the rest of the markup. can you post a jsfiddle that shows the problem?

Comment: what version of IE are you testing with? This is really important. The different versions of IE have drastically different capabilities when it comes to CSS, as not to mention different bugs.

Comment: its a magneto theme im working with and its way to complex to post the jfiddle

Comment: If you can't provide a test case, then you'll have to provide a link to the site. There is simply not enough information in your question.

Comment: Are you sure it is not overridden elsewhere? If so, have you tried "!important" with the color?

Comment: You need to post more code.  There are other things in the CSS or HTML that might be over-riding it.

Comment: while you on the subject the Blue font with the items won't show up either, but it does on FF and chrome please look at top right cart

Comment: the source code is huge, are you able to firebug it or inspect element and see if anything is overlapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like IE is applying a different font color for `.cart_price a`.  Assuming this is your markup:

```
<div class="cart_price">
    <a href="">$123.45</a>
</div>
```

Adding the red color to the `.cart_price a` rule will fix it:

```
.cart_price a {
    color: #c70000;
    float: left;
    margin: 2px 0 0 8px;
}
```